# Automation Script in maximo

Tags: jython, maximo

Please help me by providing a sample automation script (jython) for retrieving the data from database table using automation script which runs in maximo/tivoli 7.5

I'm new to get those details.

Answer (score 0):

hopefully this helps ...
a example on how to load database information into maximo via rmi

https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/a9ba1efe-b731-4317-9724-a181d6155e3a/entry/import_data_from_db_into_maximo_by_using_rmi_with_jython?lang=en

Comment: Dear Friends, I am trying to get data from asset table to display or mailing through automation script.

Answer (score 0):

You can review the Automation Scripting examples on the IBM Wiki:

https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/wikis/home?lang=en#!/wiki/IBM%20Maximo%20Asset%20Management/page/Customizing%20with%20automation%20scripts

Answer (score 0):

This code is getting data from table directly

```
from psdi.security import UserInfo
from psdi.server import MXServer

maximo = MXServer.getMXServer()
ui = maximo.getSystemUserInfo()

sessionSet = maximo.getMboSet("MAXSESSION", ui)
sessionSet.setWhere ("issystem = '1'")

s = sessionSet.getMbo(0)
servername = s.getString("SERVERNAME")
print servername
```